# How can I differentiate this with respect to a vector and also calculate Hessian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, partial-derivative

> Let $ a\in \mathbb{R}^d $ be a constant vector and $ b \in \mathbb{R}
> $ be a constant scalar. For $ x\in \mathbb{R}^d, $ define
>
> $$f(x) = \ln(1+e^{-b\;a^T x})$$
>
> Find $\nabla f(x)$ and also calculate the Hessian

My attempt:

I am not much experienced in differentiating with respect to vectors but I follow the following rules:

$\nabla (a^T x) = a \in \mathbb{R}^d$

$\nabla (x^T A x) = (x^TA)^T + Ax = (A^T + A)x \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Using the first and differentiating $log(x)$ and $e^x$ normally, I got the following:
$$\nabla f(x) = \frac{-b\;e^{-b\;a^Tx}}{1+e^{-b\;a^T x}} \cdot a \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

where $ \frac{-b\;e^{-b\;a^Tx}}{1+e^{-b\;a^T x}} \in\mathbb{R}$

Is this correct answer?
Can someone tell me how to use this to get Hessian of $f(x)$

Comment: that seems to be correct. Do the exact same thing on $\nabla f(x)$ for Hessian, but since you are differentiating a vector with a vector, you should end up with a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier for me to think about these types of problems component-wise. I'm going to use the Einstein summation notation to suppress sums and make things look nicer. The idea is that a product with matching upper and lower indices will be summed over with one sum per matching index. For example we could write that

$$C_k^m = A_{ijk}B^{ijm} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ijk} B_{ijm}$$ for some indexable objects $A,B,C.$ The benefit of this is that we can use normal scalar derivative rules instead of the multidimensional ones (and we can also use this to prove multidimensional rules).

Onto your question, we know that in Cartesian coordinates that the gradient $\nabla f$ is the row vector of partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to each coordinate. We can then say that each component of the gradient is given by

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\bigg[ \ln(1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}) \bigg]$$

where $k=1,2,\dots, n $ noting that $$a^T x = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j = a_j x^j$$

in Einstein notation. Going ahead with this derivative we have that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big[1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}\big]}{1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}       = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big[-b\;a_j x^j\big]e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}{1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}   $$

by normal scalar derivative rules. Observe that $\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^k} = \delta_k^j$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta. The definition is

$$\delta_k^\ell = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \ell=k \\[2ex]
0, & \ell\neq k
\end{cases}$$

so it's easy to see why we have this equality to the derivatives of $x^j.$

Now looking at $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big[-b\;a_j x^j\big]$ we have that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big[-b\;a_j x^j\big] = -ba_j\delta^j_k = -ba_k$$

where it is easy to see that

$$a_j\delta^j_k = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \delta^j_k = a_k.$$

Going back to the original derivative we have that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} = \frac{-b\;a_k\;e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}{1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}$$

which is exactly what you wrote! Each $k$ just represents a single component of the gradient vector.

Now as for the Hessian, we know that it is the matrix of second partial derivatives. We can compute this component-wise as we did the gradient and write

$$H_{\ell k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\ell} \bigg[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} \bigg] 
 = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^\ell \partial x^k} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\ell} \bigg[\frac{-b\;a_k\;e^{-b\;a_j x^j}}{1+e^{-b\;a_j x^j}} \bigg]. $$

To find this you will need to use the quotient and chain rules.

Once again the benefit of this is that you get to use the "normal" scalar derivative rules that you are used to using to compute this multivariable derivative. Just to be as clear as possible $H_{\ell k}$ gives the components of the Hessian matrix.

Let me know if this needs further elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, only one doubt : I have read that $\nabla f$ should belong to the same dimension as the vector you are differentiating with respect to. In my case, I get $\nabla f \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times 1}$ whereas you get $\nabla f \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times d}$

Comment: There are different conventions as to whether or not the gradient is a row or column vector. If we think of the gradient as a functional then we call it a row vector. If we think of the gradient as a vector in the tangent space of a given manifold then it is a column vector. These representations will be equivalent in Cartesian space but generalize differently. I typically use the convention that the gradient is a one form that produces directional derivatives when operating on a vector in the tangent space. This representation agrees with calling the gradient a Jacobian derivative.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the Hessian, you can rewrite your gradient as
$$\nabla f(x) = \frac{-b\;e^{-b\;a^Tx}}{1+e^{-b\;a^T x}} \cdot a = \frac{-ab}{1+e^{b\;a^T x}} $$

So your Hessian is
$$H(x) =  {\partial (\nabla f(x)) \over \partial x^T}$$

Since you're differentiating w.r.t. a row vector, you should get a row vector, i.e., $ba^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much